# Adding events to dynamically created objects

Tags: jquery

I've created a function where all drop downs on the page with the class ".dropdown" do something when changed. However adding subsequent dropdowns dynamically do not trigger the event. How can I make the dynamic dropdowns trigger the change event?

```
$(".dropdown").change(function () {
    //Do Something
});
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: `$(document).on('change', ".dropdown", function () {
    //Do Something
});`

Comment: this quetion does not show any effort for solving the issue while SO is full of same questions with great answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach change event for dynamically created `.dropdown` elements:

```
$(document).on('change', ".dropdown", function() {
    //Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '.dropdown', function () {
    //Do Something
});
```

Structure is like

```
$(static selector / parent).on('event', 'dynamically added element*', function () {
    //Do Something
});
```

*also includes the currently existing ones

Answer (score 0):

use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
 $(document).on('change','.dropdown',function () {
//Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".dropdown").live("change", function () {
            alert(1);
         });
```

Comment: beware live is dead as for jq 1.9+